# Length of Multidimensional Arrays - Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, null

I'm having an issue with the following loop I'm trying to run.

```
function syllCount(array){
    for (i = 0, x = phonemeArray.length; i < x; i++){
      sylls.push(phonemeArray[i].match(/\d/g));
      syllArray.push(sylls[i].length);
  }
}
```

Each phonemeArray element looks something like this: "AE0 B S K AA1 N D AH0 D", so the output being pushed to sylls (an empty array) would be [0, 1, 0].  However, when I try to call the length method on this element, represented by sylls[i], I get the error "Cannot read property 'length' of null".  Is there a way to get this loop get the length of each of the arrays that have been pushed to sylls and then push that result to the syllArray array?

Thanks.

Comment: Before anything, please change `i = 0` to `var i = 0`, or you will be declaring a global variable.

Comment: Where does sylls come from?

Comment: Have you declared anything as variables? You pull phonemeArray, sylls, and syllArray out of thin air and your function takes in one parameter called array that does nothing? I have a feeling this isn't the full code, could you include all that is necessary to your question, or include a jsfiddle (http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I've already declared it as an empty array above this function, but result is the same if I declare it inside this function.

Comment: ctwheels - sorry, this is just a snippet of my code.  phonemeArray, sylls, and syllArray are all declared previously.  I call this function below with phonemeArray as the parameter.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fluidddynamics/3m2mzd5g/  Here is a jsfiddle of the full code

Comment: In your jsfiddle, you declare `var sylls = [];` which is continuously resetting the sylls variable to an empty array, so you will only be able to access the first value that you enter. Once i changes from 0 to any other number you are no longer accessing anything that exists, declare `var sylls = []` outside the for loop

Comment: @ctwheels Still getting the same error once sylls is declared up top with wordArray and syllArray.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/3m2mzd5g/1/ Like this? I have it displaying the 3 arrays to show you the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misread the issue, so am just starting the answer over so isn't really long.

Based off of [your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fluidddynamics/3m2mzd5g/), this is what I came up with:

```
function syllCount(p) {
    var sylls = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        sylls.push(p[i].match(/\d/g));
        syllArray.push(sylls[i].length);
        count++;
    }
}
```

I made an [example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hc41ydaz/) that is roughly based off of how yours looked.  Let me know if I missed the mark again.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I'm not sure this was what I'm looking for.  I'm pushing the array of matches from phonemeArray[i] to the sylls array first, and then trying to push the length of sylls[i] to the syllArray array.  So I would have three arrays of the same length, one with the phoneme, one with an array of matched numbers, and one with the amount of matched numbers.

Comment: The problem is just with calling length on the sylls array.  When I log sylls it outputs something that looks like:    [[ '1', '0', '0' ],
  [ '1', '0', '0' ],
  [ '1', '0', '0' ],
  [ '1', '0', '0' ],
  [ '0', '1', '0' ],
  [ '1' ],
  [ '1', '1' ],
  [ '1', '0', '1' ],
  [ '1', '1' ],
  [ '1', '1' ] ]   But I'm not able to call length on these elements of the array, as it comes back null.

Comment: @fluidddynamics There, I rewrote the answer so it correctly addresses your issue.

Comment: Ok, this definitely looks right, but I am still getting the error  "Cannot read property 'length' of null" when I use it in my own code.  I think this is an issue with the text I am parsing, rather than the actual code.  It seems like there is a null value inside my sylls array, which is where the issue is coming from.  If i just take a selection of my data, this solution works.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Got it all working with a simple if !== null statement.  Thanks again for your help!